# How to get no of documents before commit of full-import in solr?

Tags: java, solr

In my solr data full-import, database sometime returns 0 records due to some reason.
I want to put a check if database return 0 record rollback the index.
I don't want to commit it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In first place for full indexing why does your database returns 0 results?

Can you show us what excat query you are firing for full indexing?

I could understand that DB is returning 0 results for partial indexing but for full indexing this should not be a case.

Show us the data config dot xml file that you have written for this issue.

You should fix the issue at database / query side rather than looking for solution in data import handler

Comment: thanks for your reply. see, as i mentioned above that due to some technical issue(connection break or reset of connection from database or killing the connection process of database) solr manage to get 0 result and for those exceptional cases i want to put check on solr side itself.

Comment: It is not true that Solr finishes the dataimport, if an error occurs. Read [the docs, for each Entity Processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-EntityProcessors) you can define that solr aborts the process, if an error occurs. The keyword is `onError` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

**SIMPLE ANSWER:** If there is **actually** a need to have a check before starting the data import handler, then there should be a custom implementations of `DataImportHandler` & `DataImporter` configured in `solrconfig.xml`

**EXPLAINATION:**

Custom `MyDataImportHandler` class should look something like below:

**MyDataImportHandler.class**

```
class MyDataImportHandler extends DataImportHandler {
    :
    private MyDataImporter myImporter;
    :
    :

    @Override
    public void handleRequestBody(SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse rsp) throws Exception {
        :
        :
        if(command != null && DataImporter.FULL_IMPORT_CMD.equals(command)) {
            :
            :
            // Check out DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody() for more details 
            myImporter.runCmd(requestParams, sw);
            :
        } else {
            super.handleRequestBody(req, rsp);
        }
        :
        :
    }

    :
    :
    :
}
```

**MyDataImporter.class**

```
class MyDataImporter extends DataImporter {
    :
    :
    // Check DataImporter.doFullImport() for more details
    @Override
    public void doFullImport(SolrWriter writer, RequestInfo requestParams) {
        :
        :
        // Check if count of documents in equal to 0, then throw exception
        if(docBuilder.importStatistics.docCount==0) {
            docBuilder.rollback();
            throw new Exception ("Count of documents is 0");
        }
        :
        :
    }
    :
}
```

**solrconfig.xml**

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"
        class="foo.bar.MyDataImportHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

***On a side note***, before implementing this solution, examine the need of it. I strongly believe that you may not be required to do all this. If there is any case of `connection` break/reset in database, then the Solr's default DIH will throw an `Exception` and subsequently `rollback` the index to the last successfully indexed documents.

Hope this helps you.

References:

1. [`org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-dataimporthandler/4.8.1/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DataImportHandler.java#DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody%28org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequest%2Corg.apache.solr.response.SolrQueryResponse%29)
2. [`org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-dataimporthandler/4.8.1/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DataImporter.java#DataImporter.doFullImport%28org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter%2Corg.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.RequestInfo%29)
3. [`org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-dataimporthandler/4.8.1/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DocBuilder.java#DocBuilder.Statistics)